Under which conditions does the system $Ax=0, x \geq 0$ have a non-trivial solution?
I have given a 4x4 system of the form $Ax = 0, x \geq 0$. I am interested in understanding under which conditions this system has a non-trivial solution.
Starting with $Ax=0$ it is a known result that $A$ needs to be rank-deficient. But since I am also imposing $x \geq 0$, this is not enough. For example consider the matrix
$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$. Every solution needs to satisfy $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 0$, but because of the non-negativity of $x$, this yields $x=0$.
Moreover, I tried Farkas Lemman but since $x=0$ is always a solution this did not yield much further insight.
Lastly,
I know that $Ax=0, x \geq 0$ defines a polyhedron as used for example for Linear Programming. So in order to verify if it is non-empty for specific matrices $A$ one could probably use the simplex algorithm.
But I would love to find a more theoretical answer that gives me explicit conditions, e.g. $rank(A) < 4$.

$rank(A)<4$ is necessary but not sufficient.

You have to have a zero eigenvector where the coefficients are both positive and negative.

Hi Paul, thanks for the comment! I am unsure if I understand you correctly. If you have a zero eigenvector, how can the coefficients be both positive and negativre

Hi Paul, I think I understand now. You mean that vor an Eigenvector $v$ that satisfies $Av=0$ there need to be positive and negative entries in $v$. But I am a bit unsure if this is really all you need.

You can use Motzkin transposition theorem (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Motzkin_transposition_theorem) or Gordan theorem.
